# Export Products screen is not showing all attributes

Tags: export

We have a site running `Magento ver. 1.7.0.2`.  On the Export admin screen, it used to show all the available product attributes on the screen like in the screenshot below however now it only shows up until the `Depth` option.

Additionally to not showing all the attributes, when you click `Continue` it loads a white screen where it seems to die and not export anything!

I'm at a loss as to how to fix or debug the source of this problem even.  Any help or ideas?

**How the screen looks now, cuts off after Depth attribute...**

[image]

**How the screen used to look, showing 3x more attributes**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem and solved it. Was due to the Enhanced Admin Grids extension that limited the number of entity attributes on screen. To fix you go to:
Configuration > Settings > Enhanced Admin Grids > Base Configuration, then General section, then Global Exclusions section and add an Exception for Block Type: `importexport/adminhtml_export_filter` with `*`. Hit Save and refresh the export screen.

Comment: Amazing that did the trick and worked for us, thanks a bunch as I would have never figured this out on my own!  I am curious how you guys came to this discovery?  Either way thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a custom extension installed. in the first screenshot I can see a button 'Grid Customisation' what does that do? Do you know what extension is that causes the button to appear? Have you tried removing it and see if it restores all the attributes?